# PHP curl cannot save ASP.net MVC generated cookie

Tags: php, asp.net, curl, cookies, web-crawler

I need to write a bot to login into a website and do some query, problem is this website is written in ASP.NET MVC and needs two cookies to identify user! I can save one cookie using my PHP curl but the other one .AspNet.ApplicationCookie (which is as large as ~400KB) cannot be stored!

Here is my code:

```
$ch = curl_init('MY URL...');
$cookie = __DIR__ . '/cookie.txt';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/32.0.1700.107 Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "UserName=123&Password=123");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: What happens with the cookie.txt file, it stays empty? I think you need to add the 'CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION' parameter. Example: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true); If that's not working please check your cookie.txt file permissions. It could be that PHP isn't able to write to the file because of wrong permissions.

Comment: No my cookie.txt is not empty it has all the information of one the cookies! I tried CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION option but still no joy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, ASP.net uses a mechanism to avoid CSRF attacks which is using a token field (hidden text input as "__RequestVerificationToken") and a cookie on the same page also as "__RequestVerificationToken" these tokens comes with different values but are related with each other, what you need to do for a remote login using PHP cURL is to fetch these values at the same time and posting them together if you get the __RequestVerificationToken field and get the cookie another time or vice versa, ASP.net considers this as an attack and changes values both on cookie and the field which will result to a failed login.